# How to get an array of hashes from a hash of arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have been a while thinking about how do the next operation in ruby but I am a newbie and I can't get the solution.

I have a hash of arrays:
`{text: ['1','2'], position: [1,2]}`
And I would like to have:
`[{text: '1', position: 1},{text: '2', position: 2}]`

Hope you can help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get keys (`:text`, `:positions`), and values (arrays):

```
h = {text: ['1','2'], position: [1,2]}
keys, values = h.to_a.transpose
# keys => [:text, :position]
# values => [["1", "2"], [1, 2]]
```

Then, use [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-transpose) / [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-zip) to get what you want:

```
# values.transpose => [["1", 1], ["2", 2]]
values.transpose.map {|vs| keys.zip(vs).to_h }
# => [{:text=>"1", :position=>1}, {:text=>"2", :position=>2}]

# values.transpose.map {|vs| Hash[keys.zip(vs)] }
#   ^ Use this if `to_h` is not available.
```

Answer (score 2):

Use *block* with [`#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) :

```
hash = {text: ['1','2'], position: [1,2]}
output = []
hash[:text].zip(hash[:position]) do |a1, a2| 
  output << {text: a1, position: a2}
end
output # => [{:text=>"1", :position=>1}, {:text=>"2", :position=>2}]
```

Comment: Hi Arup, how are you?

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
h = {text: ['1','2'], position: [1,2]}

h.map { |k,v| [k].product(v) }.transpose.map(&:to_h)
  #=> [{:text=>"1", :position=>1}, {:text=>"2", :position=>2}]
```